# Exsitence of element of a certain order in an infinite abelian group

Tags: abelian-groups

I came up with the following question reading this([Finite Abelian Groups question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357205/finite-abelian-groups-question)).

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Suppose there is an integer $n \ge 1$ such that $nG = 0$.
Let $m$ be the smallest integer $\ge 1$ such that $m G = 0$.

> Is there an element in $G$ of the order $m$?

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this. It is an easy to answer but nevertheless a well-posed and natural arising question.

Comment: @vadim123 Why do you ask? Do you think that  a finite abelian group and an infinite one are not different?

Comment: @vadim123 The accepted answer does use the finiteness condition.
Or do you think that all abelian groups are finitely generated?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is positive. All elements have finite order divisible by $m$, so your proof (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1361378/211913) works fine even in that case. Note that you have never used the finiteness of the group, but only the (bounded) finiteness of the order of each element.